# Grid is not refreshing and add dialog is not closing after submit, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

I am struggling with this trying to:

- Refresh the grid content from remote
- Close add dialog

After I click on the submit button but it's not working for me since the dialog still open afterwards and the grid does not reload it's content. This is how my code looks like:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";

    var manage_drugs_list_grid = $("#manage_drugs_list");
    manage_drugs_list_grid.jqGrid({
        colNames: ["Actions", "Drug Name", "Date Created"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "act", template: "actions", width: 50, align: "left"},
            {name: "DrugName", search: true, stype: "text", editable: true},
            {
                name: "DateCreated",
                search: true,
                editable: false,
                formatter: "date",
                sorttype: "date",
                formatoptions: {
                    newformat: "n/j/Y g:i:s A"
                },
                width: 50
            }
        ],
        cmTemplate: {
            width: 300,
            autoResizable: true
        },
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rowNum: 25,
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        autoResizing: {
            compact: true,
            resetWidthOrg: true
        },
        rowList: [25, 50, 100, "10000:All"],
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortable: true,
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiPageSelection: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "Id",
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        prmNames: {id: "Id"},
        jsonReader: {id: "Id"},
        editurl: "/ajax/drugs/upsert",
        url: '/ajax/drugs/get',
        datatype: "json",
        formDeleting: {
            url: '/ajax/drugs/delete',
            delicon: [true, "left", "fa-scissors"],
            cancelicon: [true, "left", "fa-times"],
            width: 320,
            caption: 'Delete form',
            msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this drug?',
            beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                var rowids = $form.find("#DelData>td").data("rowids");

                if (rowids.length > 1) {
                    $form.find("td.delmsg").html('Are you sure you want to delete all the selected drugs?');
                }
            },
            afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
                if (response.responseText === "true") {
                    toastr["success"]("The form was deleted successfully.", "Information");
                } else {
                    toastr["error"]("Something went wrong, the form could not be deleted.", "Error");
                }
            }
        },
        navOptions: {
            edit: false,
            add: true,
            search: false,
            refresh: true
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");

            if (p.datatype === "json") {
                // recreate the toolbar because we use generateValue: true option in the toolbar
                $self.jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar").jqGrid("filterToolbar");
            }
        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', {
        addtext: "Add",
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true}
    });
});
```

I have found this Oleg [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959187/719427) but  is not working for me, pretty sure I am using the wrong syntax or the wrong events at the wrong place.

**UPDATE:**

After give Google another try I have found this question/answer: [Close add dialog after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926096/close-add-dialog-after-submit) which makes me go to the [jQgrid Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Anavigator) and look through the available options in the `navGrid` and then go to [form_editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) page. After read those docs I've changed my code into:

```
.jqGrid('navGrid', {
    addtext: "Add",
    reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true}
}, {
    addCaption: "Add new drug",
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    clearAfterAdd: true,
    closeOnEscape: true
})
```

However the changes doesn't make my issue to disappear. The caption is not overwritten, after add a new record the dialog does not close, hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key doesn't make any changes meaning the dialog remains on the page and so on.

**UPDATE #1:**

After read jQgrid sources and look for some clue I give a 3rd try now by adding the following in the grid definition:

```
formEditing: {
    caption: 'Add new form',
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeOnEscape: true
},
```

Still not working.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? Something that is indicating whether or not the expected events are firing (or mis-firing)?

Comment: @Forty3 nope, nothing like that

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092147/after-add-dialog-is-not-closing) as it implies there are additional parameters which can be leveraged in your call to `.jqGrid(...)`.

Comment: I've found that one (I forgot to mention) but that answer is from three years ago almost sure that has changed. If you look at my code snippet you'll see that I was trying to do exactly the same as in the accepted answer but that is not working for me since the dialog doesn't close and the grid does not reload

Comment: If you can use the un-minified version of jqGrid, then find the `function postIt()` and place a breakpoint on the first line of that function and then again on the first line of the `complete: ` function contained in `var ajaxOptions = $.extend*{ [...]` block. This will give you step through points to figure out why the two places where `closeAfterAdd` is called may not be firing.

Comment: That is not so helpful since I have been reading the code and I have found that apparently those `closeAfterAdd` and `closeAfterEdit` are part of the `ajaxGridOptions` and I change to this configuration option but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163285/discussion-between-forty3-and-reynierpm).

Comment: @Forty3 I wasn't at my desk when you answer yesterday, I have added more info. Still not working!