# Clear previous selection only if checkbox is not clicked in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a grid setup with `multiselect: true` because I need to be able to delete more than one row at the same time. On the `onSelectRow` event I am loading some data based on the `ID` and displaying it to the end user. So far so good.

This is the example where everything works fine, the data for `ID=219109` is being displayed:

[image]

Now look at the following example:

[image]

In the example above the first row still highlighted and then I clicked a second one. Because of `multiselect` is enabled I was able to select both at the same time. The `onSelectRow` event still working properly which means is loading the data for the `ID=282006` but visually it could be confusing for the end user.

What I want to do is to reset the previous selected rows and just highlight the last one I have clicked.

For example using the same images:

- Load a fresh grid with no rows selected
- Click on `ID=219109`: highlight and select this row
- Click on `ID=282006`: clear the grid and highlight this row

However this should only happen when I click in any other place than the checkbox.

[image]

In the image above if I click on any column rather than the first one (the one having the checkbox) I should be able to clear the grid selection and choose the last one but if I click on the checkbox it does not matter because is the only way to delete more than one at the time.

I have tried the following:

```
onSelectRow: function () {
    var rowid = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    $(this).jqGrid("resetSelection");
    $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);
}
```

But it's not working since the behavior is not consistent. You can check the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/949pLpfv/2/).

Any ideas in how to achieve this?

Comment: It seems to me that you need just add `multiboxonly: true` option and remove your current `onSelectRow` code. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/949pLpfv/3/. If the user clicks multiple times on checkbox the rows will be selected. The click on another part of the row will deselect all previously selected rows and select only the clicked row. Is it what you try to implement?

Comment: @Oleg Yesssssss you are the best, many thanks. (BTW I have to more questions here in SO regarding jQgrid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289644/grid-is-not-refreshing-and-add-dialog-is-not-closing-after-submit-why) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288574/how-to-upload-a-file-on-inlineedit-or-add-actions-in-jqgrid) if you have some minutes left please take a quick look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need just add the option

```
multiboxonly: true
```

and remove your current `onSelectRow` code. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/949pLpfv/3/. If the user clicks multiple times on checkbox the rows will be selected. The click on another part of the row will deselect all previously selected rows and select only the clicked row.